# Blender isn't snapping to the grid, its shift 1 grid space away from the original

Tags: edit-mode

I'm trying to make a few modular assets. To support my quest, I'm using grid snapping. However I have noticed that when moving faces or vertices, it doesn't snap them to the grid, it just moves them 1 grid space (based on the grid space I have set 0.5 in this case).

Here is an example:

I want to move this face onto a grid.
[image]

When I move it this happens. It just passed the grid.
[image]

How do I turn on absolute grid snapping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the *Absolute Grid Snap* box in the snapping popover to enable absolute grid snapping:

[image]

Comment: Ahh perfect and it was right there.. That helps allot